# How to read computational graphs

Tags: graph, computation

I am trying to gain a better understanding of computational graphs.  I've been given the following examples with the question 'Assume a modern Pentium processor.  This machine has 6 functional units: 1 load, 1 store, 2 integer, and 2 floating point.  Can this machine execute the following graphs?'

[image: Computation Graphs]

I have researched the topic on the web and can't find good information on how to read these. I've dug into my computer systems textbook to no avail. Can anyone help me decipher these and solve the examples? Or at least point me to a good resource for learning how to read these?

Thanks in advance!
Cheers